# How can i convert a numpy.array to image without saving?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I want to display a `numpy.array` as image without saving. I have a code to do it but it is not efficient. Could you please help me to find more efficient code for that ? thank you so much in advance. Best regards.

`plt.imsave('ttt.png', np.array(new_img).reshape(m, n), cmap=cm.gray)
fff = cv2.imread("ttt.png")
cv2.imshow('frame',fff)`

Comment: OpenCV in Python uses numpy arrays to represent images. Just display it...

Answer (score 1):

Use [pyplot.imshow](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) directly:

```
plt.imshow(np.array(new_img).reshape(m, n), cmap=cm.gray)
```